# Trying to cancel sprite animation before the script finishes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit of a beginner so please have patience with me.
I'm working on building a movement for a player model where it cycles between a set of sprites for up, down, left, and right facing movement but if I move in another direction before the current cycle is finished the script begins to overlay sprites from both directions on each other. I'm seeking a way to cancel the current sprite rendering when a new direction is input. Any suggestions?

````
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] moveArray;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public PlayerController playerController;


    IEnumerator ChangeSprite()
    {
        if (playerController.horizontal >= .1f && playerController.horizontal > playerController.vertical)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[6];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[7];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[8];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[7];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
        if (playerController.horizontal <= -.1f && playerController.horizontal < playerController.vertical)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[3];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[4];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[5];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[4];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
        if (playerController.vertical <= -.1f && playerController.vertical < playerController.horizontal)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[0];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[1];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[2];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[1];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
        if (playerController.vertical >= .1f && playerController.vertical > playerController.horizontal)
        {
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[9];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[10];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[11];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
            spriteRenderer.sprite = moveArray[10];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (playerController.vertical != 0f || playerController.horizontal != 0f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ChangeSprite());
        }

        else if (playerController.vertical == 0f && playerController.horizontal == 0f)
        {
            StopCoroutine(ChangeSprite());
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Handling animations this way will cause a lot of issues, one being the issue you are currently facing. I would recommend using the Animation component and animating your object. Here is a [Brackey's Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&ab_channel=Brackeys) on the subject. Should help a lot - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `StopCoroutine` incorrectly, you need to store either the `IEnumerable` returned from your animation call, or the `Coroutine` returned by `StartCoroutine`, and pass *that* to `StopCoroutine`:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...

    private Coroutine _movementAnimation;

    // ...

    void Update()
    {
        if (playerController.vertical != 0f || playerController.horizontal != 0f)
        {
            // Store the Coroutine into a variable to be able to refer to it later
            _movementAnimation = StartCoroutine(ChangeSprite());
        }

        else if (playerController.vertical == 0f && playerController.horizontal == 0f && _movementAnimation != null)
        {
            // Stop the running coroutine, and clear it so we don't try to stop it many times.
            StopCoroutine(_movementAnimation);
            _movementAnimation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

While Unity's documentation kind of implies coroutines are somehow special, the `IEnumerator` and `yield return` syntax are C# features, and in C# calling a function will always execute its code, never re-use previous invocations.

This means that when you tried to `StopCoroutine` in the old code, you were stopping a coroutine that was never even started, because it was a brand new one just returned from the method that made it.

---

With that said, I don't think this is a good way of implementing animations, you have lots of magic numbers in your code, which means that you would have to change the code to be able to change the amount or order of the frames.

I would recommend looking into unity's [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html) component, or if you want to roll your own, consider a more data-driven design that receives the frame order and delays from some sort of data structure.

Comment: Thank you very much I've tried to take advantage of the Animator component with greater success. I appreciate your suggestions and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the "animation" and "animator" components in unity.

Hard coding your own animators can be very tedious and you should avoid it at all costs.

Watch a video or two on how animations work in unity and once you have done that. You can disable the animation component to stop the animation